# put if else statement within return function in react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why this don't work? I remember I once get it working splitting the html part into 2 function, but this time I want to make the code look shorter, but it seems like I can't do if else statement in my return function of render now.

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3],
       isEdit: true
     }
   },
   renderEditForm(){
   return(
   <div>
   <input type="text" />
   <button>save</button>
   </div>
   )
   },
   renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
         <li key={i}> isEdit ? this.renderEditForm() : {item}</li>)
     )
   },
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnvn800k/1/

Not sure why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The content inside `<li>` should be enclosed within the `flower bracket`.

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/8b0grbdd/